map not found by target_frame on RVIZ with Velodyne LiDAR
We have Velodyne LiDAR connected to RVIZ on a robot dog. We are able to achieve point-cloud data when changing the fixed frame to any other of the dog's joints except map. We are also able to create a file location when creating a map. The map assigned to target_frame is unable to be found. Hence, RVIZ is not able to receive map to then successfully conduct SLAM with point-cloud data.
Any suggestions?
Goal: achieve
We have achieved LiDAR data after changing the base link, but once that is done, the publish 2d nav goal does not execute.
